# /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Illegal seek collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am running my program on linux server and it was compiling and  running fine then i made another directory and tried to compile it  in that directory and it was throwing me error:
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Illegal seek 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I am taking files from a directory and making a list of it, then passing this list to my parser, parser performns it's functionality and outputs on a pipe, i created the pipe by using mkfifo pipename
before compiling and created file filename.pipe too.

Comment: It is updated kindly help me if you can.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to help you with that description. You need to provide _concrete_ information about exactly what you're doing. Code, build script/makefile, directory structure, whatever is relevant. Someone should be able to reproduce your problem from the information in your question.

Comment: I sounds like the program had set a library search path or include search path (or both) which included the original directory your built in. Or, you simply copied everything after running `./configure` and the configure cache is still pointing to the old path. If you build that way, delete the configure cache and run `./configure` again. If it builds with a Makefile, try running `make clean` and building again. Without seeing the actual error you get, we are just left giving your most common reasons.

Comment: I solved it my self. It was occurring because i was making the pipe in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the execute file name for the program. My error was fixed by doing that.

g++ -o m filename

Try running the above line with your file name.